# Assign a value to a variable only after the previous setTimeout command has executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

have a look at the following code:

```
$("#menu_choice").click(function () {
    $('#content_home').animate({
        "left": "-5000px"
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout("$('#content_home').hide();", 600);    
    $('#content_creations').show();

    var x = $("body").width() / 2;
    var y = $("#content_creations").width() / 2;
    $('#content_creations').animate({
        'left': x - y
    }, 1000);
});
```

My problem is that `x` is being calculated `before $('#content_home').hide() is executed`.

In what way, may I "oblige" the code to calculate `x` after `#content_home` has been hidden? Of course, i need the `setTimeout` command. The reason i want that is to `find` the `right dimension` of the browser window with or without its vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Is there a user-interface related reason that you want `setInterval()`? Or is it just an attempt to delay your code execution?

Comment: Try to use `$.when([code]).then([code])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **setTimeout** try using $('#content_home').hide()

```
$("#menu_choice").click(function () {
    $('#content_home').animate({
        "left": "-5000px"
    }, 1000);

    $('#content_home').delay(5000).hide("fast", function(){
    //here calulate div width
    });
    $('#content_creations').show();

    var x = $("body").width() / 2;
    var y = $("#content_creations").width() / 2;
    $('#content_creations').animate({
        'left': x - y
    }, 1000);
});
```